# Numba TypingError upon calling a numpy.ufunc generated with numba.vectorize

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, vectorization, numba

I am calling the function `f(x,a)` inside of `F(x,a)` as follow

```py
import numpy as np
import numba
from numba import vectorize


@vectorize('float64(float64, float64)', nopython = True, target = 'parallel')
def f(x,a):
    out = np.sign(x)* np.exp(-1* (np.absolute(x/a) - 0.5)**2)
                
    return out
    
    

@numba.jit(nopython = True)
def F(x,a):
    out = np.zeros(10)
    for i in range(10):
        f(x,a)
    
    return out
        
a = 1.
x = np.random.rand(5*5).reshape((5,5))

#Then this works fine
f(x,a)

#But this does not work
F(x,a)
```

Calling `f(x,a)` works fine but not `F(x,a)` where I get the following error message:

```py
TypingError: cannot determine Numba type of <class'numpy.ufunc'>
```

What surprises me is that if I set `target = 'cpu'` in the decorator of `f(x,a)`, everything will work fine. I noted that in that case:

```py
type(f)
>>> numba.npyufunc.dufunc.DUFunc
```

whereas, when I set `target = 'cpu'` in the decorator of `f(x,a)` (the broken case), I get:

```py
type(f)
>>> numpy.ufunc
```

Anyone could help me understand what is going on ?